# android getFromLocationName() sometimes returns null

Tags: android, locationmanager, google-geocoder, android-gps

My code only works for like 80% of adresses and i dont understand why i dont get a result sometimes. If an adress doenst work i just change the street number from 1 to 2 and it works.

My String adress which i provide looks like this:
"Street No, Postcode, City"
Or for US,CA,EN :
"No Street, Postcode, City"

```
public Map<Location, String> getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address;
    Location res = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Map<Location, String> resMap = new HashMap<Location, String>();
    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        String addressText = "";
        if(location.getAddressLine(0) != null && 
              location.getAddressLine(1) != null)
            addressText = location.getAddressLine(0) + 
               " - " +location.getAddressLine(1);
        res.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        res.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        resMap.put(res, addressText);
        Log.d("LocationUtil: ", addressText);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return resMap;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search the same address using a [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)? Just to check if Google knows this address. Probably some addresses are missing from their database. Google is not an official postal service, so the coverage might be less than 100%.

Comment: I didnt try a web service but i typed the adress manually into google maps via browser and google maps have found it

Comment: maps.google.com and Android geocoder might use different endpoints to get the data. As far as I know the web service couldn't find addresses related to businesses in the past, this changed recently with a new version of forward geocoder, but Android geocoder I guess is still using the "old" approach.

Comment: Do anyone have good expierence with any service i could use instead? And is the current geocoder i am using limited to an amout of requests ?